# Add a class to each item in choice list

Tags: jquery, css, symfony

I am using the FormBuilder in Symfony2 and have an entity field that I display using a choice list.  It looks fine, but is on the long side, and I want to add css to indent items based on their groupings, this way it is easier for the user to see when the groups change.

I can use jQuery to add in a class based on the value of the option item, but feel that it would be cleaner if I set the css class directly in the form's class.  Does anyone know how to set a class for each individual option, not on all of the options?  I can add a field in the entity with the css class and that is my preferred way to set the class and I am hoping this can be added as an attr somehow in the formbuilder.

Right now my generated html looks like this:

```
<form name="filter" method="post" action=""><div id="filter">
    <label for="choices">Choices</label>
        <select id="choices" name="filter[choices][]" class="chosen-select" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="100">A</option>
            <option value="105">B</option>
            <option value="110">C</option>
            <option value="200">D</option>
            <option value="205">E</option>
            <option value="215">F</option>
            <option value="300">G</option>
            <option value="400">H</option>
            <option value="405">H</option>
            <option value="430">J</option>
            <option value="450">K</option>
            <option value="500">L</option>
            <option value="502">M</option>
            <option value="504">N</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" id="search" name="filter[search]">Filter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I need to adjust all of the option tags to include a class, but the class will change and is related to the value.  I would like to render something like:

```
<option value="100" class="100">A</option>
<option value="105" class="100">B</option>
<option value="110" class="100">C</option>
<option value="200" class="200">D</option>
<option value="504" class="500">N</option>
```

Now that I'm thinking about it, maybe it is easiest using jQuery to find the value of each option and add a class attr based on each value, but then my logic is mixed with my view.  I would like to add the class in the formbuilder if possible, but I need the class to changed based on the value of the option.  My css will indent the items in the drop down menu so that groups are visually easy to identify.

Comment: some code/markup/fiddle would really help us understand your issue and provide you a solution

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using custom form theme. For example, you can define custom block `form_my_widget` and use it to render your choice list.

More info about custom blocks - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Inside of your custom theme, you can apply `class` attribute to individual `option` tags.

Comment: Which form widget do I need to override - select_widget?  I've read about it but saw the section on 'Knowing which block to customize' and was not sure where I can find the widget I need to override and where I can see it's existing code.  I think this may be the way to do it if I can find the widget.

Comment: I guess, if you don't have any more `select`s in that template, then you could override `choice_widget_options block`. However, I believe it is better to create your own custom block and use it just to render your choice list.